# Need help PHP SQL (PDO) Beginner

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL table using PDO.

Here is add.php:

```
    // include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
echo "Connexion success...";


$sq = DB_CONNECT::$con->query($table);
if ($sq) {
    echo 'Table created...';
}
?>
```

And here is the connect class db_connect.php:

```
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        return $this->connect();

    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database and selecting database
    try {
        $con = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}
}
```

When I try to query the database, I get this error message:

Connexion success... Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DB_CONNECT::$con in /public_html/toutain/add.php on line 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is mixing quite a few approaches. It's currently just a utility function wrapped in a class.

Instantiating with `new DB_CONNECT;` is pointless, since the `new PDO` handle from your method isn't kept as property, like `$this->con`.

Using `return $con` won't actually return the PDO instance over/via the constructor. Your `new DB_CONNECT` would only ever return a `DB_CONNECT` object with the local `$con` variable disposed; thus leaving no way to actually call any PDO methods.

Currently you can only utilize it as:

```
$pdo = DB_CONNECT::connect();
```

Then invoke `$pdo->query()` from there.

```
// connecting to db
$pdo = DB_CONNECT::connect();

$result = $pdo->query($table);
if ($result) {
    echo 'Table created...';
}
```

Comment: With your recommendation, I get : Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want, sorry... can you edit my code ?

Comment: Where is the difference between $pdo and $db, it's just a variable right ? I did what you wrote but I still have the same Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object. when in DB_CONNECT, I call $con = new PDO(), should I deletete $con ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a variable name. Your `::connect()` method should stay as it is in your original post. But sorry, I can't make out what's wrong with your usage otherwise. Works for me as depicted.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 $sq = DB_CONNECT::$con->query($table);
```

Should be

```
 $sq = $db->query($table);
```

Your class definition should be

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

 class DB_CONNECT extends PDO {

      public function __construct() {
           try{
               parent::__construct(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
           }catch(PDOException $e){
               die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
           }
      }  
 }
```

I use a similar class at work so this should constructor should work for you, and you can delete the connect function

Comment: I think he should have a function `query()` in the class for that..

Comment: This time with your code, I have this message : Connexion success... Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::query() in /public_html/toutain/add.php on line 11

Comment: oh right, your class needs to extend PDO, edited my post

Comment: I wouldn't recommend extending `PDO`. In any case, constructors don't return anything.

Comment: oh man, missed that too

Comment: I don't understand ? ^^why extend my class ? the connexion is successfull... I still have the same problem